# Run MLO Files in QEMU

Tags: emulation, ram, qemu, armv7, cortex-a8

I have an ARMv7 Cortex-A8 chip, with a TI AM335x embedded chip (my chip very close to Beaglebone Black controller). I compiled the whole system stack, starting from the `MLO` files, to `u-boot`, to the Linux kernel `zImage`, and to the Linux user space as well as the programs that should be running on my controller. However, for specific analysis cases, I might need to emulate the architecture and the system stack of my controller in, say, QEMU. As I was researching about the boot sequence of most embedded devices, the sequence goes as the following: `MLO` -> `u-boot` -> kernel -> user space -> etc.

As I began to emulate the system, I started with `qemu-system-arm` (since I am using an ARM 32-bit device, hence ARMv7), and passed the following machine type (since this is the only Cortex-A8 device available in QEMU): `realview-pb-a8`, and the following CPU: `cortex-a8`. I also loaded my compiled `u-boot.bin` using the `-bios` argument. However, nothing shows up on the VGA display other than `Guest has not initialized the display (yet)`, and nothing shows up on the serial IO. My guts tells me I have to load the MLO before the `u-boot` file, but how would I do that, if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a low-level program (like u-boot, or the kernel) that is built for one kind of Arm embedded board on another. realview-pb-a8 is completely different hardware to the AM335x SoC, and the guest code will simply crash as soon as it tries to do anything with the hardware.

You would need to have a model of the right hardware in QEMU to run this software, but QEMU doesn't have a model of that SoC, so you can't, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmm... so I guess I have to build QEMU from source, and then add entries for the hardware I am emulating with the CPU + RAM + peripherals for my hardware specification. Too bad QEMU doesn't support TI machines out of the box, but at least I get to learn QEMU API :) .